# Open URL with array iOS SDK

Tags: ios, arrays, nsurlconnection

I want to open an URL within an array, but it don't work. This is my code:

```
NSArray *platformarray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:iphonestring,ipadstring,androidstring,blackberrystring, windowsstring,nil];


    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://xxx.nl/appofferte.php?hoedanigheid=%@&bedrijfsnaam=%@&naam=%@&email=%@&telefoon=%@&platformen=%@", hoedanigheid, bedrijf.text, naam.text, email.text, telefoon.text, platformarray];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Who can help me to put the array in 1 variable?

Comment: does it not posible for you to do it like this ,,NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://xxx.nl/appofferte.php?hoedanigheid=%@&bedrijfsnaam=%@&naam=%@&email=%@&telefoon=%@&platformen=%@%@%@%@%@", hoedanigheid, bedrijf.text, naam.text, email.text, telefoon.text,iphonestring,ipadstring,androidstring,blackberrystring, windowsstring ];

Comment: be more specific which array in which variable

Comment: @Dilip No, the PHP-file send an E-mail, so it is 1 variable. Is it possible to send "platformarray" in 1 variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the items in the array are strings then you can combine them with:

```
NSString* combined = [platformarray componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

Comment: He still proceed to load the url, but can't complete it. No E-mail send

Comment: Do you get an error in your `- connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error` delegate function?

Answer (score 0):

```
hoedanigheid=%@&bedrijfsnaam=%@&naam=%@&email=%@&telefoon=%@&platformen=%@", hoedanigheid, bedrijf.text, naam.text, email.text, telefoon.text, platformarray];
```

change platformarray to `[platformarray objectAtIndex:thePlatformThatIWant];` eg:`[platformarray objectAtIndex:0];`

```
hoedanigheid=%@&bedrijfsnaam=%@&naam=%@&email=%@&telefoon=%@&platformen=%@", hoedanigheid, bedrijf.text, naam.text, email.text, telefoon.text, [platformarray objectAtIndex:thePlatformThatIWant]];
```